# Dart assert if not null in constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

How to assert if a parameter is not null in a Dart constructor?

```
const CardStackCarousel({
    Key key,
    this.itemBuilder,
    this.itemCount,
    int backgroundItemCount,
    this.controller,
    this.offsetAboveBackcards: 10.0,
    this.minScale: 0.8,
    this.verticalAxis: false,
  })  : backgroundItemCount = backgroundItemCount == null ? itemCount - 1 : backgroundItemCount,
        assert(backgroundItemCount < itemCount, 'background item must be less than itemCount'),
        super(key: key);
```

With the code above, I am getting a error:

```
The method '<' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

When the user does not specify the backgroundItemCount property. So my idea is maybe we should only assert if this property is not null. But I can't figure out how to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're not asserting a `CardStackCarousel` property - that probably have a `backgroundItemCount` as well - , you're asserting the argument that you're receiving through the constructor, which, by your logic, could be null.

When you call:

```dart
backgroundItemCount = backgroundItemCount == null ? itemCount - 1 : backgroundItemCount
```

You're not assigning a new value to the input received, you're probably saving it to a local property. What you're actually doing in the line above is:

```dart
this.backgroundItemCount = backgroundItemCount == null ? itemCount - 1 : backgroundItemCount
```

Which is why the assert fails, because it doesn't check the `this.backgroundItemCount`, it checks the properties received through the constructor, the `backgroundItemCount`.

I will cite a phrase from [Dart official documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors):

> Warning: The right-hand side of an initializer does not have access to
> this.
>
> ...
>
> During development, you can validate inputs by using assert in the initializer list.

Which explains why you can't check `this`, because it's still "static" validating your inputs - at the moment of the right-side evaluation, it doesn't have the instance yet.

---

If you still need to make sure that the `backgroundItemCount < itemCount`, you should simply `assert(backgroundItemCount == null || backgroundItemCount < itemCount, 'If background item is supplied, it must be less than itemCount')`.

Like so:

```dart
const CardStackCarousel({
    Key key,
    this.itemBuilder,
    this.itemCount,
    int backgroundItemCount,
    this.controller,
    this.offsetAboveBackcards: 10.0,
    this.minScale: 0.8,
    this.verticalAxis: false,
  })  : backgroundItemCount = backgroundItemCount == null ? itemCount - 1 : backgroundItemCount,
        assert(backgroundItemCount == null || backgroundItemCount < itemCount, 'If background item is supplied, it must be less than itemCount'),
        super(key: key);
```

Comment: So how to assert  (backgroundItemCount < itemCount) ?

Comment: I have added a comment on how to still check for the `itemCount` to be larger than the `backgroundItemCount`

Comment: I don't get your answer, I tried `const CardStackCarousel({
    Key key,
    this.itemBuilder,
    this.itemCount,
    int backgroundItemCount,
    this.controller,
    this.offsetAboveBackcards: 10.0,
    this.minScale: 0.8,
    this.verticalAxis: false,
  })  : backgroundItemCount = backgroundItemCount == null ? itemCount - 1 : backgroundItemCount,
        assert(backgroundItemCount != null && backgroundItemCount < itemCount,
            'background item must be less than itemCount'),
        super(key: key);`  but the assertion always fail when user omit backgroundItemCount

Comment: Where do you I put this `assert(backgroundItemCount != null && backgroundItemCount < itemCount, 'background item must be less than itemCount')` ? Can you please put a final version of the constructor ?

Comment: Well, I have updated your constructor to check it when the input that you received is != null, because as I've said, you can't check your instance property, as you don't have the instance yet.

Comment: okay, you have a typo then, earlier you said ...null &&...  now it is  ...null ||...  . I edited your answer, check edit